# How to integrate Qualtrics surveys into my android application?

Tags: api, survey, qualtrics

I have an android application that I would like to get feedback from users. I found Qualtrics to be a great service to do this. I have never implemented any survey's with in my applications. I would like a pop up at the end of the application to ask the user if he/she would like to take the survey.

Is there any tutorials on using Qualtrics web services or examples?

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need a web service. A Qualtrics survey is just a web link so just open the survey link in Chrome.  You can pass parameters from the app to the survey in the url. Just define the parameter names in the Qualtrics survey flow and they will be included in the response data.